# How to achieve the statusbar as the same effect with the arctoolbox‘s tool called in ArcMap add-in?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, c#, add-in

How to achieve the statusbar as the same effect with the arctoolbox‘s tool called in ArcMap add-in?

i do not know how to use the progressbar as a result of my project involves in a large mount of data calculate and it is very complicated.So I choose the startbar the same effect
with the arctoolbox‘s tool(when the tool was called ,the stausbar show ,while the work is finish ,the statusbar is hidden).

I want to achieve the same effect as below (picture link)：

[image: while Arctoolbox’s tool is called]

[image: while the tool finish the work]

Comment: I am not certain if this is what you need, but it may be as easy as unchecking the *Always run in foreground* box on the tool's properties, that way it will run in the background using the background Geoprocessing progress bar and finished indicator.

Comment: You may also want to experiment with ArcPy's [**progress dialog box**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000032000000).

Comment: thanks，I Can only use c#,can you provide some demo using in c#

Comment: Forgive my poor English